# how do I mock an array and List in EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Hello I am looking to test out a class using Junit and EasyMock, Only issue is I have an issue understanding what to do with Arrays and List of objects in terms of mocking the data.

```
public void hereisClassIamMocking(@Nonnull final List<object> manyObjects,
        @Nullable final weirdArrayObject[] waoItems)
```

Does anyone know how to do this , while continuing to use EasyMock ?

Comment: It's not at all clear why you'd want to mock them - it's especially unclear when you've got a *method* called `hereisClassIamMocking`...

Comment: your so right... I just noticed that when I renamed the method ( that was a poor substitution of a name ) .

Answer (score 1):

You can only mock objects, and [an array isn't an object type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8), so you'd fail at creating a mock of any kind of an array.  You could create the mock of a list like any other mock you've ever created; you'd just get an unchecked assignment warning from the compiler.

That aside, you should **never** mock your parameters.  They represent actual input to the function, and are the most concrete thing you can provide in your test.  I would question why you have to pass a list an an array together (it seems to me that the function is begging to be refactored), but you would actually want to pass the list and array to your method for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock this method(Even though it looks a bit weird to me)
you should be doing it like this

```
hereisClassIamMocking(ListObject,arrayObject);
Easymock.expectLastCall();
```

as you need to mock void method, it should be done with `expectLastCall` property of easymock.